# Spring boot: disable security auto configuration

Tags: java, security, web, spring-security, spring-boot

I have multipart web project. `Web Admin` part contains:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

Main project build file contains:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: "spring-webmvc", version: springVersion
compile(group: 'org.springframework.security', name: "spring-security-web", version: springSecurityVersion) { exclude(module: 'spring-jdbc') }
```

Spring Boot application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class WebAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebAdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But when I'm doing http request to my admin part I'm getting user and password in my `AuthenticationProvider`:

```
auth.getPrincipal() -> user
auth.getCredentials() -> caeebd3a-307b-4edf-8f2f-833fad9ebc00
```

How I can disable auto security?

Comment: What do you want to disable exactly? If you do not include spring-security as a dependency, spring-boot will not not autoconfigure it for you. If you want a different configuration, you need to configure it by yourself.

Comment: I want disable completely creation of default user/password

Answer (score 7):

Even I was facing the same issue. So, I added below code.

- Case 1: If you have NOT activated 'ACTUATOR':
  `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })`
- Case 2: If you have activated 'ACTUATOR':
  `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {      org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})`

Answer (score 4):

if you look at [spring boot's spring.factories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories) (release 1.3.5 at the time of writing), you can see security has 4 autoconfigure classes:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration,\
```

You probably want to also disable SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration (or all 4 of them)